# How can I trigger a function only when only child divs are clicked using event bubble?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, event-bubbling

```
const handleMenu = e => {
    console.log(e.target);
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

I want to console the event when a child div is clicked. for example:

```
    <div onclick={handleMenu}>
        <button>My orders</button>
        <button>Payment</button>
    </div>
```

So, I want to trigger the `handleMenu` function only when those buttons are clicked and not to trigger when the area of parent div is getting clicked except those button areas. How can I do it?

and yes I am using `reactjs`. If any alternative way to do that with `reactjs`, it will be more helpful.

Comment: Why not adding click events on the buttons.

Comment: Add a event to the child div and stop propagation

Comment: @BimalPariyar, Because I have 8 to 10 child components. so adding event in every component is not efficient. I need to create a reusable functional way.

Comment: May be we can check the target type like e.target.tagName === "BUTTON",
and perform the functionality.

Comment: @BimalPariyar, yup it's a way! But it's require using tag name carefully so that child tag name don't match up with parent tag name. and if using multiple tag name in child components it requires more conditioning. Is there any other easier way to do it?

Comment: If I understood the problem then,
Creating a stand alone component for div with buttons and importing that component where ever needed would be the better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in following way. Attach to the event callback on the child like following ..

```
if(event.currentTarget != event.target ) return;
....
```

target event = element that triggered event.

currentTarget event = element that has the event listener.

Comment: Thanks @Abu Sufian. That's what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

In React,
Add a ref to div element, check if the target is equal to ref to see if it's not self event

```
  const myRef = React.useRef(null);
  const handleMenu = (e) => {
  myRef.current!==e.target
  console.log(myRef.current);
  e.stopPropagation();
  };

 return (
   <div ref={myRef} onClick={handleMenu}>
     <button>My orders</button>
     <button>Payment</button>
   </div>
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add return false at the end of function. This will prevent the rest of the triggers caused by outer elements.

```
const handleMenu = e => {
    console.log(e.target);
    return false;
}
```